# A Basic Question on What a Universal Set Can Contain

Tags: elementary-set-theory

***Disclaimer**: I'm not a trained mathematician, so I apologise in advance if my language is not precise enough or not up to par in general. I am always happy  to learn.*

I was watching this [lecture](https://youtu.be/kCEAFjjTJyU?t=3421) on logic, and at the 57th-minute mark the professor introduces what he calls the "inductive definition of sets". In it he refers to two components (at 59:00): a set $A \subseteq X$, where $X$ is the universal set, and $P$, a set of operations on elements of $A$ (or a Cartesian product thereof) .

Now, up until this point, both in the lecture and in my general maths reading, a universal set despite its name had some sort of "common feature" to all its elements/subsets -- like the set of reals numbers, the set of complex numbers, the set of all possible outcomes of an experiment, all the humans in the world, and so on; but never all real numbers and all scalene triangles. Even when reading about the the field axioms, the operations '$+$' and '$*$' seem to have a disjointed existence from $F$.

So, my question(s) is (are): is it valid to consider $P$ to be a subset of $X$? And in general, can the universal set contain pretty much anything one wants? Was my view of what it can contain biased by the contexts in which I encountered it?

My two go-to resources for looking up definitions, Wikipedia and Wolfram Mathworld, weren't particularly helpful or at the least weren't clear to me.

Comment: No, $P$ is usually not a subset of $X$. $X$ can be essentially any set. An example is $X=\mathbb C$, $A=\mathbb R$, and $P=\{+,-,\cdot,\div\}$.

Comment: In that case, where does $P$ exist?

Comment: Good question. $P$ usually is a finite set, so we don't usually care.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand this point. I'm assuming that by a "finite set" you mean a set with a finite number of elements. How are the two related? Or in other words, why does that make us "not care"?

Comment: The idea is that since there are only a finite number of operations we care about (usually) on a set, we don't bother worrying about what universe it belongs to, since there aren't any set-theoretic issues that come up in dealing with the operators.

Comment: Hm... okay. (I was hoping for something more precise. I always feel a bit uneasy when "we don't bother with that" comes up in a mathematical context. :-) ) Are there any issues that might crop up if a set such as this had been infinite (countable or otherwise)?

Comment: I understand your discomfort. I think the rationalization is that in most branches of math, you have some $n$ operators, and that's it. The collection of operators don't really change, even as the sets of elements do. Which is why we can be a little carefree with them. If there were an infinite number of operators, we would need a universal set and a bit more precision when talking about operators for the same set-theoretic issues.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Comment: "Even when reading about the the field axioms, the operations '+' and '∗' seem to have a disjointed existence from F."  Yes,  the set of operations are *not* elements of the set.  They are things you can do to a set.  Why is this a concern? To me this is no more paradoxical then you can have a collection of books, and a bunch of people who *read* books, but the people who read the books are not books themselves.  Maybe you are thinking there must be some universal set that has "everything to do with fields". But even if you did, *that* set, needn't be the set of field elements.

Comment: I guess I'd never seen those operations defined as being part of a set before. But once a set is defined, one (me, anyway) immediately anchors it to some universal set, either definite or abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some work on "lexicon" may help...

We have two related - but distinct - concepts.

That of [Universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set):

> "a set which contains all objects, including itself."

It is not an "easy" concept to deal with from the mathematical point of view.

And that of [universe (or: domain of discourse)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse):

> "generally refers to the collection of objects being discussed in a specific theory/discipline."

This second term can be used to describe e.g. arithmetic: the *universe* is the collection (usually denoted with: $\mathbb N$) of all *natural* numbers: $0,1,\ldots$ with the usual arithmetical operations defined on them: $+, \times$, where e.g. $+ : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.

In this case, the operations on numbers are not themselves numbers: they produce numbers as output from numbers received as input, and thus they are not elements of $\mathbb N$.

This means that we may say that $\mathbb N$ is the *universe* of arithmetic, but it is not an *universal set* (it does not contain everything).

Thus, according to the couple of concepts above, how can we understand the statement:

> [In] the "inductive definition of sets" [the author] refers to two components: a set $A ⊆ X$, where $X$ is [the ?] universal set, and $P$, a set of operations on elements of $A$.

We may understand $X$ as the universal set, i.e. the "universe" as set theory, provided that we do not try to "manage" it with the tools of the theory.

In it we have a set $A$ with a collection $P$ of operations: $P = \text {op}_1, \text {op}_2, \ldots$

In this case, the set $A$ is a "universe", like $\mathbb N$ above, on which the said operations act.

The operations, in turn, a set themselves. Assuming that they are binary operations, we have that: $\text {op}_1 : A \times A \to A$ is a subset of the cartesian product $(A \times A) \times A$.

If we read $X$ as the "universal set", then obviously $\text {op}_1$ belongs to $X$, but $\text {op}_1$ is not an element of $A$, the "universe" of the theory.